# section and subsection on a double-sided document

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, scrlayer-scrpage

In the header of my twosided document should be on the left side always the author. On the odd pages should be on the right side the section and on even pages the subsection also on the right side.

I tried it with the code above but the subsection is not displayed. How can I do that?

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside=semi,BCOR=6mm, usegeometry=true]{scrartcl}
    \usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2cm, headsep=0.75cm, headheight=1cm, marginparwidth=4cm, marginparsep=0.5cm, footskip=1cm]{geometry}
    \usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
    \pagestyle{scrheadings}
    \clearscrheadfoot 
    \cfoot{\pagemark}
    \lohead{author}
    \lehead{author}
    \rohead[section]{subsection}
    \rehead[section]{subsection}
    \ihead{\headmark}

\begin{document}
\section{test}
Lorem \newpage
\subsection{test}
ipsum 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want:

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside=semi,BCOR=6mm, usegeometry=true]{scrartcl}
 \usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2cm, headsep=0.75cm, headheight=1cm, marginparwidth=4cm, marginparsep=0.5cm, footskip=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets pagestyle scrheadings automatically
\clearpairofpagestyles
\cfoot{\pagemark}
\lohead{author}
\lehead{author}
\rohead{\leftmark}
\rehead{\rightmark}

\begin{document}
\section{test}
Lorem \newpage
\subsection{test}
ipsum 
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

[image]

---

**Update**:

If there should be the section in the header if there is no subsection and on pages with a new section even if the page is even:

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside=semi,BCOR=6mm, usegeometry=true]{scrartcl}
 \usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2cm, headsep=0.75cm, headheight=1cm, marginparwidth=4cm, marginparsep=0.5cm, footskip=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets pagestyle scrheadings automatically
\automark[section]{section}% <- added
\automark*[subsection]{}% <- added
\clearpairofpagestyles
\cfoot{\pagemark}
\lohead{author}
\lehead{author}
\rohead{\leftmark}
\rehead{\rightmark}

\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\section{test}
\lipsum[1-15]
\subsection{test}
\lipsum[16-35]
\section{second section}
\lipsum[36]
\subsection{another subsection}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is almostly what I need. Now if there is a section for the first time but it should show the subsection the header on the right side stays empty. Is there someway that it always shows section if is mentioned for the first time so the header doesn't stay empty? So that it always shows the section if there is one on the page and otherwise alternately the section and subsection.

Comment: See my updated answer.