# Tableofcontents with footer but without header

Tags: table-of-contents, scrlayer-scrpage

The header should be empty in the tableofcontents. The footer should contain the page number. The following code (which comes from another question which I cannot find anymore) does not display the footer. How can I change the code so the footer is displayed.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2cm,]{geometry}
\automark[section]{section}
\automark*[subsection]{}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\cfoot{\pagemark}
\lohead{author}
\lehead{author}
\rohead{\leftmark}
\rehead{\rightmark}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}
\setcounter{page}{1}

\tableofcontents

\clearpage
\pagestyle{headings}

\section{as}
\subsection{d}
\subsection{d}
\section{as}
\subsection{d}
\subsection{d}
\section{as}
\subsection{d}
\subsection{d}
\section{as}
\subsection{d}
\subsection{d}
\section{as}
\subsection{d}
\subsection{d}
\section{as}
\subsection{d}
\subsection{d}
\section{as}
\subsection{d}
\subsection{d}
\section{as}
\subsection{d}
\subsection{d}
\section{as}
\subsection{d}
\subsection{d}
\section{as}
\subsection{d}
\subsection{d}
\section{as}
\subsection{d}
\subsection{d}
\section{as}
\subsection{d}
\subsection{d}
\section{as}
\subsection{d}
\subsection{d}
\section{as}
\subsection{d}
\subsection{d}
\section{as}
\subsection{d}
\subsection{d}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\cfoot*{\pagemark}` notice asterisk

Comment: Off-topic: In this example the `\setcounter{page}{1}` does not make sense. In other context it even could provoke warnings because of destinations with the same identifier. So you should be careful with such manual settings of the page counter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\clearpairofpagestyles` removes all predefined header and footer contents for both page styles `scrheadings` and `plain.scrheadings` (`plain` is an alias for `plain.scrheadings`).

You can use the optional argument of `\cfoot` etc. to set the content for `plain.scrheadings`. Example:

```
\cfoot[plain]{scrheadings}
```

There is also a starred version `\cfoot*` which uses the same content for both `plain.scrheadings` and `scrheadings`:

```
\cfoot*{\pagemark}% same as \cfoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
```

Additional remarks:

In an onesided document there are no even pages. So the `\rehead` and `\lehead` in your MWE do not make sense if you do not add option `twoside` or `twoside=semi`. Additionally the optional argument of `\automark` is ignored for onesided documents by default. You have to add `autooneside=false` to the `scrlayer-scrheadings` options to use the optional argument of  `\automark` in a onesided document.

Suggestion for `twoside=semi` as in [your other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/467722/43317):

```
\documentclass[12pt,
  twoside=semi% <- added
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2cm,]{geometry}
\automark[section]{section}
\automark*[subsection]{}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\cfoot*{\pagemark}% <- changed
\lohead{author}
\lehead{author}
\rohead{\leftmark}
\rehead{\rightmark}

\BeforeStartingTOC[toc]{\pagestyle{plain}}
\AfterStartingTOC[toc]{\clearpage}

\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

If you remove the optional argument of `\BeforeStartingTOC` and/or `\AfterStartingTOC` you get the same settings for all lists controlled by KOMA-Script package `tocbasic`, eg. LoF and LoT.