# Header with doublesided document

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, double-sided, scrlayer-scrpage

[This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/467893/tableofcontents-with-footer-but-without-header) is already quite close to what I need.

The only issue with this solution is that it shows the sections on the odd pages and the subsections on the even pages. However, for the first time the section appears it should always be printed. Indifferent if it is an odd or an even page. After the section is mentioned for the first time in the header the subsection and section should be alternately in the header. 
If there is a chapter without subsections and only one section the section should be always displayed in the header.

Moreover, the pagenumber should be displayed in the bottom right of the page.

Hopefully by the following exemple it should become clearer:

```
\section{1}
\subsection{1.1}
\subsection{1.2}
\subsection{1.3}
\section{2}
\section{3}
\subsection{3.1}
\subsection{3.2}
```

This should give the follwing output:

p.1 1
p.2 1.1
p.3 1
p.4 1.3
p.5 1
p.6 2
p.7 2
p.8 3
p.9 3.1
p.10 3

```
 \documentclass[12pt, twoside=semi]{scrartcl}
    \usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
    \usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2cm,]{geometry}
    \automark[section]{section}
    \automark*[subsection]{}
    \clearpairofpagestyles
    \rofoot*{\pagemark}
    \refoot*{\pagemark}
    \lohead{author}
    \lehead{author}
    \rohead{\leftmark}
    \rehead{\rightmark}



\BeforeStartingTOC[toc]{\pagestyle{plain}}
\AfterStartingTOC[toc]{\clearpage}


\begin{document}
\section{1}
ads
\newpage
\subsection{1.1}
  \newpage
\subsection{1.2}
    \newpage
\subsection{1.3}
    \newpage
     d
     \newpage
\section{2}
    \newpage
    d
    \newpage
\section{3}
    \newpage
\subsection{3.1}
    \newpage
\subsection{3.2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please -- as usual here -- show us a short compilable code you have so far ...

Comment: If you want the page number in the foot, you should not use `\rohead*{\pagemark}` and `\rehead*{\pagemark}` but `\rofoot*{\pagemark}` and `\refoot*{\pagemark}`. I cannot say anything to your other question because the code example shows only two pages but your numbering example talks about ten pages. So IMHO the code does not show the problem. However, have a look to the additional `\right…mark` and `\left…mark` commands in the KOMA-Script manual.

Comment: @Schweinebacke Thanks for your comment. I already had a look at the `\rightmark` command but it didn't answer my question how to establish a hierarchy that the section is always displayed for the first time and then the subsection and section alternating. (Except if there is no subsection in the section) You're right about the code. I added `\newpage` so it spreads over several pages.

Comment: Your code example still does not correspond with your numbering example. However: Is it correct, that in the page head you always want the first section or subsection heading that is shown on a page? And please note, my recommendation to have a look to `\right…mark` means not only `\rightmark` but also `\righttopmark`, `\rightfirstmark` and `\rightbotmark` (and same for `\left…mark`). One more note: `\newpage\newpage` make no sense and is the same like only one `\newpage`.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the first section or subsection heading printed on a page to have also in the page header, you do not need `twoside=semi`. In single-side mode `\headmark` is always `\rightmark` which is the same like `\rightfirstmark` (see the KOMA-Script manual for more information about these marks). So with

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2cm,]{geometry}
\automark{section}
\automark*{subsection}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead{\headmark}
\ihead{author}
\ofoot*{\pagemark}

\BeforeStartingTOC[toc]{\pagestyle{plain}}
\AfterStartingTOC[toc]{\clearpage}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{section 1}
\newpage
\subsection{subsection 1.1}
  \newpage
\subsection{subsection 1.2}
    \newpage
\subsection{subsection 1.3}
    \newpage Test
     \newpage
\section{section 2}
    \newpage Test
    \newpage
\section{section 3}
\newpage
\subsection{subsection 3.1}
    \newpage
\subsection{subsection 3.2}
\end{document}
```

you get the heading sequence:

- page 1: *empty*
- page 2: 1 section 1
- page 3: 1.1 subsection 1.1
- page 4: 1.2 subsection 1.2
- page 5: 1.3 subsection 1.3
- page 6: 1.3 subsection 1.3
- page 7: 2 section 2
- page 8: 2 section 2
- page 9: 3 section 3
- page 10: 3.1 subsection 3.1
- page 11: 3.2 subsection 3.2

To your *moreover* question: If you want to place something in the page footer you have to use a `\…foot`-command instead a `\…head`-command. See figure 5.2 in the KOMA-Script manual and the explanation of the commands in section 5.4 of the KOMA-Script manual.

If you want the same result with `twoside=semi` (or `twoside=true`) it would be better to explicitly use `\rightfirstmark` instead of `\headmark`, because in this case `\headmark` would be `\rightmark` on odd pages but `\leftmark` (same like `\leftbotmark`) on even pages. And in this case you need indeed the optional argument of `\automark` and `\automark*` and, if the elements in the head and foot should not alter their alignment, you cannot use `\ohead` and `\ofoot`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside=semi]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2cm,]{geometry}
\automark[section]{section}
\automark*[subsection]{subsection}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\rohead{\rightfirstmark}
\rehead{\rightfirstmark}
\lohead{author}
\lehead{author}
\rofoot*{\pagemark}
\refoot*{\pagemark}

\BeforeStartingTOC[toc]{\pagestyle{plain}}
\AfterStartingTOC[toc]{\clearpage}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{section 1}
\newpage
\subsection{subsection 1.1}
  \newpage
\subsection{subsection 1.2}
    \newpage
\subsection{subsection 1.3}
    \newpage Test
     \newpage
\section{section 2}
    \newpage Test
    \newpage
\section{section 3}
\newpage
\subsection{subsection 3.1}
    \newpage
\subsection{subsection 3.2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. `twoside=demi` is needed for BCOR and I wasn't sure if this influences my question so I just added it to the MWE. Your answer does not fully address my question. I'm fully aware that the question is not clear enough as I struggle quite a bit with describing the desired result and I'm sorry for that. So I edited the question. The difference from your answer to my desired result is that the section and subsection should be alternaly.

Comment: @danik I think you mean `twoside=semi`. I've added an example with it. However, with alternating BCOR IMHO alternating alignment of the elements in the page head and foot would make more sense.

Comment: What do you mean by alternating alignment? And is it now clearer how the output from your answer differs from the desired result?

Comment: @danik With `twoside=semi` the BCOR is added to the right margin on left pages and to the left margin on right pages. So `twoside=semi` is made for double-sided printing. But with double-sided printing, it makes not sense to have, e.g., the page number always aligned to the right margin (using `\refoot` and `\rofoot`). Instead it would make more sense to have the page number always aligned to the *outer* margin (this what `\ofoot` makes). Similar to the head: It would make more sense to still use `\ohead` instead of `\rohead` and `\rehead`.

Comment: @danik … On the other hand for a single-sided document it makes more sense to have BCOR always added to the left margin, so `twoside=false` would be better.

Answer (score 1):

Your desired result is unusual, but maybe the following does what you want.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside=semi]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2cm,]{geometry}
\automark[section]{section}
\automark*[subsection]{}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\rofoot*{\pagemark}
\refoot*{\pagemark}
\lohead{author}
\lehead{author}

\newcommand*\lastheadentry{}
\rohead{%
  \ifstr{\lastheadentry}{\leftmark}
    {\rightbotmark\xdef\lastheadentry{\rightbotmark}}
    {\leftmark\xdef\lastheadentry{\leftmark}}%
}
\rehead{%
  \ifstr{\lastheadentry}{\leftmark}
    {\rightbotmark\xdef\lastheadentry{\rightbotmark}}
    {\leftmark\xdef\lastheadentry{\leftmark}}%
}

\BeforeStartingTOC[toc]{\pagestyle{plain}}
\AfterStartingTOC[toc]{\clearpage}

\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{section 1}
\lipsum[1-7]
\subsection{subsection 1.1}
\lipsum[8-14]
\subsection{subsection 1.2}
\lipsum[15-20]
\subsection{subsection 1.3}
\lipsum[21-28]
\section{section 2}
\lipsum[29-35]
\section{section 3}
\lipsum[36-40]
\subsection{subsection 3.1}
\lipsum[41-44]
\subsection{subsection 3.2}
\lipsum[45-50]
\end{document}
```

Result:

- page 1: *empty*
- page 2: section 1
- page 3: subsection 1.1
- page 4: section 1
- page 5: subsection 1.3
- page 6: section 2
- page 7: section 3
- page 8: subsection 3.1
- page 9: section 3
- page 10: subsection 3.2